# Obtaining list views in Jenkins from nested view plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pom.xml

I have developed a plugin which has its extension point from ListViewColumn but now I have run into problems when combining it with another plugin, [Nested View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nested+View+Plugin).

My plugin enables one to select jobs in the current view and make modifications with one button press. But when a view resides inside a nested view, I can't find that view (from my java code and jelly scripts) and no modification can be made. in columnHeader.jelly I execute

```
${it.getHeaderText(view.name)}
```

where `getHeaderText()` is defines as

```
public String getHeaderText(String viewName) {
    Hudson.getInstance().getView(viewName);
    // access all jobs from the return object of .getView(viewName)
    return viewName;
}
```

This works fine with regular List Views but whenever I enter a nested view's list view, `getView(viewName)` returns null.

Upon further investigation I've noticed that nested views show up when calling

```
Hudson.getInstance().getViews();
```

which returns only the views in the toplevel of the whole Jenkins instance (no views inside the nested views). Here I have a nested view which shows and is an instance of hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView. But I don't seem to be able to do anything with this object.

**Therefore I'm wondering how I go about to get ALL list views from a Jenkins instance?**

I believe I have to define a dependency in my pom.xml file as such

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>nested_view.plugins.hudson</groupId>
    <artifactId>nested-view</artifactId>
    <version>1.526</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

in order to be able to make use of the objects which are instances of hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView. But when adding this to my pom.xml, it doesn't seem to work. hovering above the dependency tag (second line of the code block above) I get the message

> Missing artifact hudson.plugins.nested_view:nested-view:jar:1.526

I rather find a way to get all views via core methods and objects. But if I have to add a dependency in order to get the list views and jobs inside the nested views, how do I get it to work?

---

Sidenote:

[This issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23283) is what I want to do but `getViews()` returns View objects which do not contain View objects. Also, I want to do this in java. But this does not help me at all...

// Bogge

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to my problem!

Since I have access to all the jobs individually in the current view without knowing which view I am in, I could add each job to a list in the backend and just scan the URL to see if someone changed view (then I would clear and re-add the jobs again).

It would still be appreciated if someone had an answer to how you get access to objects of other plugins and how you add depencencies correctly though.

Cheers!